# How to adjust IMG for screen size / device in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I'm binding to some images.  They are 500x500 
How do I adjust the so the the image appears or is resized according to the device or screen size?

thanks inadvance

```
     <img ng-src="{{slide.img_url}}">
```

Comment: Can you do it with CSS? http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units

Comment: What's the syntax for img?  How do I use it?